# Package software separately from content that is CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 license

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I have content that is CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (see http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/), can software that uses it still be produced commercially and just let the user download the content separately?

In other words, if I have commercial software that uses the content with CC license, can the software still be distributed as commercial and just not be distributed with that content... OR, would that still violate that CC license and the software therefore can't be commercially sold?

If someone knows the answer or can point me to a place to find out the answer, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant link top the Creative Commons FAQ: [Does my use violate the NonCommercial clause of the licenses?](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Does_my_use_violate_the_NonCommercial_clause_of_the_licenses.3F)

Comment: A common wish from people who license their work under an NC license is "I don't want any business people to exploit my work for profit". But they often don't realize that "commercial activity" and "profit-oriented activity" are two different things.

Comment: @user1902183 Did you create an account and repost this question at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/230608/cc-by-nc-sa-can-i-sell-plugins-for-a-non-commercial-software ?

Comment: @M.Dudley No, and that question is not what I am asking either. I want to use *content* that is NonCommercial, not software. I want to build software that uses that content and other content as well.

Answer (score 1):

The NC-clause Creative Commons licenses are often criticized for not defining well what "non-commercial" means exactly, so it doesn't provide much legal certainty for the licensor or licensee.

The [full legal text of the CC-BY-NC-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/legalcode) (which is the one which "counts". What you linked to is just the "human-readable" synopsis) reads:

> c.You may not exercise any of the rights granted to You in Section 3
>   above in any manner that is primarily intended for or directed toward
>   commercial advantage or private monetary compensation.

(The rights granted in section 3 are the rights to distribute or publicly perform the work)

The [Creative Commons FAQ](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Does_my_use_violate_the_NonCommercial_clause_of_the_licenses.3F) says:

> Whether a use is commercial will depend on the specifics of the situation and the intentions of the user. [...]
>   There will always be uses that are challenging to categorize as
>   commercial or noncommercial. CC cannot advise you on what is and is
>   not commercial use. If you are unsure, you should either **contact the
>   rights holder for clarification**, or search for works that permit
>   commercial uses.

Emphasis is mine and my recommendation what you should do. Licenses are a communication tool used by creators to communicate how they wish their work to get used. When a communication tool fails, you should try to communicate in a different way.

So try to find the creator(s) of the NC content and ask them if what you want to do is commercial activity in their opinion or not.

Some aspects which might be interesting to them are:

- Is the NC content required by your application or is it just an optional supplement?
- Will you use the NC content to promote your application?
- Does the user actively choose to download the NC content or does the application download it automaticaly?
- Do you allow people who didn't buy your software to obtain the NC content for free?
- Is the user aware which parts of the content are CC-BY-NC-SA? (more important for the BY and the SA than the NC)

Comment: To answer your first question:
I don't think I would want to ask the owner as that will complicate matters. I think they want the entire world to be free and will oppose this even if it's actually legal and fine to do this.

I am mostly curious if other software vendors have done this. RedHat vs CentOS come to mind. I think CentOs ships without some things because of that type of license with some packages, but you, as a user can download those yourself.

Comment: Your bullet questions:
1) NC content is optional, but a good start so you, as the user, don't have to create so much yourself upfront.
2) No, won't use it to promote. More like in the install (or support) will point them that they can download that content to start with if they want.
3) User would have to actively choose to download and have an expert on my software help them install it.
4) The owner of that NC content already does allow that. I would have nothing to do with that.
5) Yes, the user would be made aware as that is not par to my system. Just something that already exists out there

Comment: Would your answer change based on what I commented above?

Comment: @user1902183 I can not answer these points because I am not the creator of the work. When you believe that the creators would not agree with you using their content in this way, then you shouldn't do it. You are looking for a loophole in their license to do something which is against their wish. This is ethically quite questionable in my opinion.

Comment: Well, I am either not explaining this well or I would disagree with you regarding this being ethically questionable. I guess, I can make the question much easier. If I create software that CAN POTENTIALLY use the CC content and my client chooses to download and use it with my software instead of creating his own content, would my software fall under the restrictions of the CC content because it's designed to work with format that the CC content is in? Frankly, the more I explain the question, the more it feels to me that the answer is that it's not going to effect my software license. Agree?